# Merge tags [tag:sony-xperia-sp] and [tag:xperia-sp]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-cleanup

The [sony-xperia-sp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sony-xperia-sp) and [xperia-sp](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xperia-sp) tags refer to the same device, and, as such, their tags should be merged.

I'm not sure what else to say about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, thanks for pointing it out.